# UIButton title not editable after upgrade to Xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uibutton

Perhaps it's a coincidence and some other unintended change is responsible, but for whatever reason, my button stops responding to programmatic title changes.

The button belongs to a UITableViewCell. I am trying to change the title as

```
if(someA){
  self.myButton.titleLabel.text=@"A";
}else{
  self.myButton.titleLabel.text=@"B";
}
```

Also the button, which I define in storyboard, has a default text, which I set in Attributes Inspector, as "HI" (as part of troubleshooting).

When I run the app, all the other subviews of the cell are changed/set appropriately except the button's title. For all the cells the button always says "HI". And I am using one setter method to set content for all the views: `-(void) setMyData:(Something*)myData`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
[self.myButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

If the button is disabled, you should use `UIControlStateDisabled`.

Also, what might be the case (which would be a coincidence, like you said) is that you're using `self.` instead of `cell.` since you said the button is in a table view cell.

Maybe you meant something like this?

```
[cell.myButton setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```